# checking for null in Hashtable get() operation

Tags: java, collections

According to java docs for class `Hashtable`:

```
This example creates a hashtable of numbers. It uses the names of the numbers as keys:

   Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers
     = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
   numbers.put("one", 1);
   numbers.put("two", 2);
   numbers.put("three", 3);

To retrieve a number, use the following code:

   Integer n = numbers.get("two");
   if (n != null) {
     System.out.println("two = " + n);
   }
```

why it is using  `if (n != null) {` during get() operation in above code when Hashtable does not allow nulls in keys and values?

Had it been written for HashMap then it would be OK as HashMap allow nulls in keys and values but why it is using it for Hashtable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just good practice since the [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) method returns `null` if the specified key doesn't exist in the Hashtable.
In the above code example we could omit this since we know that the `"two"` key is there, but that is often not the case in real life applications.

Answer (score 3):

get returns null if the key is not present in the map/table.

Answer (score 3):

You could write

```
if (number.containsKey("two")) {
    Integer n = numbers.get("two");
    System.out.println("two = " + n);
}
```

while this is clearer it has two problems.

1. It is slower because it accesses the map twice.
2. It has a potential race condition if the collection is updated in another thread.

Given the thread safe Hashtable has been chosen, it appears that performance was less important than thread safety so the second reason is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

get returns Null as value if the specified key does not exists